# Does Shimano cassette tool work on Campy cassette?

Tags: cassette, campagnolo

I have a Campagnolo 10-speed cassette on the way, and I just want to know if I'll need a new cassette lockring tool to install it. I already have the tool for Shimano/Sram cassettes. In the pictures I looked at, the splines on the lockring look similar, but not quite the same:

[image: shimano cassette]
[image: campagnolo cassette]

**-- EDIT --**

[This is the tool I have.](http://www.parktool.com/product/cassette-lockring-tool-fr-5) And [this is the tool I'm supposed to have.](http://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-bottom-bracket-tool-BBT-5-FR-11) The splines *may* have fit, except the diameter is off by 0.6 mm, which sounds like just enough to make it incompatible. So I guess the answer's no. Damn Campagnolo, always making things harder...

Comment: Does the tool documentation state it works with both?

Comment: @Frisbee -  Documentation? Are you serious? I had this tool for years, the documentation (if it even came with any) is long gone.

Comment: Why do you need to get hostile? There is this thing called the Internet where you can look up documentation. If you don't have  a part number on *your* tool do current tools support both?   Really you expect SE to know if a tool you don't disclose will support both.  Yes -1

Comment: OK, fair enough. I've updated the info.

Comment: Why *Damn Campagnolo*? There's Campy equipment, then there's the rest. They and Shi?mano are competitors, one cannot expect them to make moving to a competitor's gear easy. In the case of Sram, they have a deal with Shi?mano.

Comment: Campagnolo tools fit old Shimano freewheel splines. Implying when Shimano designed their cassettes they made them incompatible with the old tools. so it should be _Damn Shimano_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, I just got the cassette, and the Shimano tool definitely does not fit.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent use of photos.  Based on that I'd say it might fit but the spline engagement would be poor.   Note that the width of each spline appears to be smaller in the campag.

**Answer**: Given the cost of each of these cassettes, you would be best off buying and owning the right tool.